# solace monitoring: looking for prometheus exporter

Tags: solace

Is the a way to have a solace prometheus exporter?

For example let the prometheus mon server export its metrics as promehteus compatible web service?
Or to use something like the PushGateway for the metrics over topic?

Answer (score 1):

I mean time we created an exporter:
https://github.com/dabgmx/solace_exporter
https://hub.docker.com/r/dabgmx/solace-exporter